# Partial support of Passkey on Android - what does it means? how is it working?

Tags: android, samsung, passkey

I’ve recently activated PasseKey on https://passkeys.io and Github on my Samsung Galaxy S23 Android 13 and 14.

I’m looking where is stored the private part of the passkey on my device - (for instance if I want to revoke it).

For information:

- I’m not using Google Credential Manager neither Samsung Pass.
- Github enable me to use the Passkey only for 2nd factor authentication I cannot authenticate directly with the passkey button it gives me a message telling me ther is no passkey
- Same for passkey.io
- But once I filled login/password (on both Github and Passkey.io) it asks me to unlock the passkey with biometry (fingerprint in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webauthn is the basis for FIDO and Passkeys. It seems that Android introduced the capability for Smartphone to act as a FIDO security key a few years ago. So here is the mixup between two technologies.

On my smartphone it’s asking me to configure a Passkey but actually it’s using the FIDO security key which is automatically setup once you configured a biomtric authentication or PIN.

The messages offered by the differents websites passkeys.io, Github and my Smartphone are all misleading. It’s not using a Passkeys but a FIDO security key. Hence if I want to revoke the private key I have to remove my PIN and all biometric configured.

Next step make passkeys working on my Smartphone - but this is a another story.